# How to strip text out of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I currently have data in a pandas dataframe that is in the form:

```
parameter1  23432552
parameter2  23647324 this is another parameter value
parameter3  43874328 this value is a thing as well
parameter4  4.34e-03
```

There are multiple columns with data in the same form, so I want to run a command that will take each numeric value, strip off any text and convert it into a usable float. I have used some regex to clean it up this far, but am not aware of a way to match any given text. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Will the values be always in the second position as your sample or they can be in any position? Because if they are,  `df.col.str.split().str.get(1)` would do

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most straightforward, but you could extract that include digits, `.`, `e` and `-`:

given:

```
>>> df
            0                                         1
0  parameter1                                  23432552
1  parameter2  23647324 this is another parameter value
2  parameter3    43874328 this value is a thing as well
3  parameter4                                  4.34e-03
```

Something like:

```
df['newcolumn'] = pd.to_numeric(df[1].str.extract('([-\.\de]+)'))

>>> df
            0                                         1     newcolumn
0  parameter1                                  23432552  2.343255e+07
1  parameter2  23647324 this is another parameter value  2.364732e+07
2  parameter3    43874328 this value is a thing as well  4.387433e+07
3  parameter4                                  4.34e-03  4.340000e-03
```

Comment: Interesting! So that automatically drops the text at the end of the number?

Comment: It just extracts the capture group in your regex, which can be formulated as a float (I don't know how stable it is, I bet an exception could be found, but this could at least point you in a direction)